# How to run maven build command in ruby script

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm new for ruby and would like to learn ruby.

I'm wring a script for that I need to how can I execute maven build command from Ruby script.

I would like to execute below command in my ruby script. appreciate if anyone can help me how to do this.

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests=true
```

Answer (score 0):

You could enclose it in backticks:

```
`mvn clean install -DskipTests=true`
```

There are several other ways you can execute system commands in ruby - you can find a more comprehensive list [here](http://shiroyasha.io/running-shell-commands-from-ruby.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will check this.